# how to image display one by one next image when click the next button?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am beginner of iPhone. I have taken the array in that i have pass the all images but images not display when I click next button..

my code is

```
images= [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                        nil] retain];  
-(IBAction)Next
{

    currentImage++;
    if(currentImage +1>=[images count])
    {
        currentImage=0;
        NSLog(@"print:%@",currentImage);
       UIImage *img=[images objectAtIndex:currentImage];
        [animalphoto setImage:img];


    }
    else
    {
        currentImage++;
        NSLog(@"hello:%@",currentImage);



    }
}
```

but next button click often time button image not display often time so give any suggestion and source code

Comment: your code, will only display a new image when the currentImage index-counter is higher than the count to display the image at index 0, in another word; the logic is not right. u should only reset the counter to 0 when its equal to the count, and display a new image anyway with the new index.

Comment: What is `currentImage`?  You are changing it as if it's a number but printing it as an object.

Answer (score 0):

just put the two lines of if statement after nslog to the else part also then the problem is solved